# how can i fix this list index issue, or is there a better way to handle a 'user account'

Tags: python-3.x

```
balance=UBal[UName.index(name)]
```

what's wrong with this code?
it keeps ending the program

1. 'name' is a string input by a user, and 'name' will be in the list 'UName'
2. I want the index number from 'name'
3. using this index number I want to get an integer from the list UBal
4. I want this integer assigned to 'balance'

this doesn't happen, the program just stops and the 3 red '>>>' is shown

these are the lists

```
['user one', 'user two', 'user three', 'user four'] #usernames
['100', '200', '300', '400'] #money
```

my main goal is to be able to get a particular user's account to be accessed.
and their money to be managed

- check balance
- deposit/withdraw money
- delete account

I thought that if i used a code like what i gave at the top, i'd be able to handle a particular account, but if there's a better method, please do tell.

EDIT:

```
UName=[]
UIdNo=[]
UBal=[]

UserNames=open("UserNames.txt", "r")
UserIDs=open("UserIDs.txt", "r")
UserBalances=open("UserBalances.txt", "r")

# Duplication of data from data storage into empty lists
with open("UserNames.txt") as UserNames:
    UName = [line[:-1] for line in UserNames]

with open("UserIDs.txt",) as UserIDs:
    UIdNo = [line[:-1] for line in UserIDs]

with open("UserBalances.txt",) as UserBalances:
    UBal = [line[:-1] for line in UserBalances]

def handle_user():
    name=input("Please enter the user's name again")
    if name not in UName:
        print("incorrect username")
        handle_user()
    print("Please Select an action to perform:\n")
    print("[ <1> Check Balance            ]")
    print("[ <2> Deposit cash             ]")
    print("[ <3> Withdraw cash            ]")
    print("")
    print("[ <97>Remove account           ]")
    print("")
    print("[ <98>Main Menu                ]")
    ans=input(">> ")

    balance=UBal[UName.index(name)]

    if ans==1:
        print("Account Balance of", name, "is", balance)
        print ("Your account balance is" )
        menu_actions['handle_user']()

    elif ans==2:
        print("Please enter a deposit amount:\n")
        dep=input(">> ")

    elif ans==3:
        print("Please enter a withdrawal amount:\n")
        wit=input(">> ")

    elif ans==97:
        del1=input("Are you sure you want to delete this account?")
        print("1.YES")
        print("2.NO")
        if del1==1:
            del2=input("CONFIRM ACCOUNT DELETION")
            print("[ <1> YES              ]")
            print("[ <2> NO               ]")
            if del2==1:
                print ("The account of accountholder NAME is being deleted")
                filestore.deleteaccount(self.username)
                print ("The account has been successfuly deleted")
                menu_actions['main_menu']()
            elif del2==2:
                print("Please Select an action to perform:\n")
                menu_actions['handle_user']()
            elif choice !='1' and choice!='2':
                menu_actions['handle_user']()
        elif ans !='1' and ans!='2':
                menu_actions['handle_user']()

    elif ans !='1' and ans!='2' and ans!='3' and ans!='97' and ans!='98':
                print("Please select a valid option:\n")
                menu_actions['handle_user']()
    return
```

Comment: Post the rest of your code please? I tried that statement and it works fine.

Comment: @JonahHaney i posted parts of the code that i thought might be needed only.

Comment: Could you provide the whole error message? Assuming that your names are unique the code seems to work.

Comment: Learn more about [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Nurzhan, I don't get any error message, when i enter '1', to check balance, the programs just ends, (the three red '>>>' marks come up)

Comment: @angelo, But you can enter the name? Right?

Comment: @Nurzhan, yes, at    name=input("Please enter the user's name again") i can enter the username, and then i can go onto the next menu, there when i select option <1>, it ends.

Comment: also, the same thing happens when i try this                                         
`>>> numtwo=["one","two","three"]`
`>>> numtwo.index('one')`  `>>>0`
`>>> bal=[100,200,300]`  `bal.index(100)`  `>>>0`
`>>> balance=bal[numtwo.index('one')]`
`>>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem why nothing happens after you enter `1` is that you're comparing the variable `ans` of type string with integers 1, 2, 3 and 97. Change it to:

```
if ans == "1":
    # your code

elif ans == "2":
    # your code

elif ans == "3":
    #your code

etc
```

At least it will fix your current problem. I could not run your further code since I don't have this method `menu_actions`.